# Python NameError: name is not defined (variable names already defined but I get error)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to run the following codes. I get the error NameError: name 'XXXXX' is not defined.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    land_dir = "C:/Users/mb/Documents/Land"
    MOD_dir = "C:/Users/mb/Documents/MOD"


def search_land_name(path):
    """to get the land list file name"""
    output_list =[]
    pt=os.listdir(path)
    for item in pt:
        if str.find(item,'B3.TIF') != -1: #satisfied conditions
            output_list.append(item[:-6])

    return np.unique(output_list) 

    for item in land_file_list:
        print(item)
        LD_QA_name = item + "QA.TIF"
        LD_B1_name = item + "B1.TIF"
        LD_B2_name = item + "B2.TIF"
        LD_B3_name = item + "B3.TIF"
        LD_B4_name = item + "B4.TIF"
        LD_B5_name = item + "B5.TIF"
        LD_B6_name = item + "B6.TIF"
        LD_B7_name = item + "B7.TIF"
```

print(LD_B3_name)

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [8], line 1
----> 1 print(LD_B3_name)

NameError: name 'LD_B3_name' is not defined

Any suggestion please.

Comment: What is the sequence of steps that you believe leads to any such thing as `LD_B3_name` being defined?  It's only assigned inside a function that does not appear to ever be called, the assignment would never take place anyway because it follows a `return` statement, and it's a local variable so it doesn't exist outside of the function.

Comment: If the code is indented exactly the same as the one you've posted, then `LD_B3_name` is not defined in the namespace where you're trying to print it, exactly as the error suggests. `LD_B3_name` is local to the function `search_landsat_name` only.

Comment: Instead of a whole bunch of similarly named variables like `LD_B3_name` -- why not have a single dictionary? You could return that from the function and then have all the names available to the calling code.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I am a novice and I don't have any clear idea. I am wondering when I run the whole code I don't get any error but with only printing variables. Do you think I can export my processed data with this matter?

Answer (score 0):

`LD_B3_name` is locally defined inside your function `search_landsat_name`.
That means that the variable only exists inside your function.

If you want to access the variable outside of `search_landsat_name` you can simply return the variable:

```py
def search_landsat_name(path):
    # some code
    return LD_B3_name

LD_B3_name = search_landsat_name(path)
print(LD_B3_name)
```

But keep in mind that `LD_B3_name = search_landsat_name(path)` creates an independent variable. If you change the value it doesn't affect `LD_B3_name` inside your function.

Check out `global` vs `local` variables to help you understand this more.